# Compare if elements in string array exists in another list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have an string array and a list of string. For example,

```
string[] stringArray = {"car", "bike", "truck"};
List<string> stringList = new List<string>{"car_blue", "car_red", "truck_yellow", "ship_black", "rocket_orange"};
```

From the array and list, I want to compare stringArray with stringList and retrieve items that are in the stringArray and is also part of the stringList. 
Eg: the items retrieved should be, 'car_blue', 'car_red' and 'truck_yellow'?

Comment: what have _you_ tried? where is _your_ code?

Comment: i've tried "stringList.Intersect(stringArray);", but it found no matches.

Comment: Well, "car" is not "car_blue". "car_blue" is "car_blue".

Comment: is it necessory that strings in `list` will always have '_', and first part of string should be matched with strings in `array` ?

Comment: nope, I have skip the '_' but the first part of the stringList must be matched with the strings in the array.

Comment: @LittleFlyingTurtle if ' _ ' will not be there in your strings of `List`, you should edit your question with this clarification. and also comment on the answer regarding the same.. I guess answer of Lucifer will help you in all cases (with and without " _ ")

Comment: If the elements in the stringList is something like 'land\\car_blue', 'sea\\ship_black'...Can how can I retrieve the items with 'car' in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best way where you don't have to use split is

```
string[] oneMinEnabledTime = stringList.Where(x => stringArray.Any(ele => x.ToLower().Contains(ele.ToLower()))).ToArray();
```

or if you want list

```
List<string> oneMinEnabledTime = stringList.Where(x => stringArray.Any(ele => x.ToLower().Contains(ele.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: i've tried your way but I still not able to retrieve the list of items i wanted.
However, the items inside my list look something like this: 'land\\car_blue', 'sea\\ship_black'... I cant figure out what is wrong with the method.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ' `Where` to filter the `stringList` using the parts before the `_`:

```
var result = stringList.Where(x => stringArray.Contains(x.Split('_')[0]));
```

Comment: i would add `.ToList();` to better evelute the result

Comment: x.Split('_')[1] is also important.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `Split` by `_` to get all tokens, then you can use `Intersect...Any`:

```
var itemsInBoth = stringList.Where(s => stringArray.Intersect(s.Split('_')).Any());
```

If you want to ignore the case, so also accept `Car_Yellow`:

```
var itemsInBoth = stringList.Where(s => stringArray.Intersect(s.Split('_'), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any());
```